# remove common elements of two arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client

I want to remove common elements of two arrays in jquery.
I have two arrays:

```
A = [0,1,2,3]
B = [2,3]
```

and result should be `[0, 1]`.

Please help

Comment: Did you try something ? For example looping ?

Comment: pls help me with some inbuilt function.

Comment: BTW filter returns common elements in two array  ie. [2,3]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can filter array A by checking its elements position in array B:

```
C = A.filter(function(val) {
 return B.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WgykC/)**

Comment: filter and indexOf are not supported in some browsers, notably IE.

Comment: Only very old versions of IE. It's fine for current ones.

Answer (score 7):

ES6 version of Milind Anantwar's answer. May require Babel.

```
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const B = [2, 4];
const C = A.filter(a => !B.includes(a));
console.log(C) // returns [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Set type from ES6.  Then the spread operator to build an array from the Set.  A Set type can only hold unique items.

```
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const B = [2, 4];
const C = [...new Set(A,B)];

console.log(C);



(4) [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the library [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#styles).

Say you have two arrays,

```
var a = [0,1,2,3];
var b = [2, 3];
```

First find the union.

```
var all = _.union(a, b);
```

Then find the intersection.

```
var common = _.intersection(a, b);
```

The final answer should be the difference between the union, and the intersection.

```
var answer = _.difference(all, common)
```

Comment: Including an entire library just to de-dupe a couple of arrays is massive overkill.